# SQL Server: Drop Table with FK

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

On table "A" depend about 30 other tables via FK to "A.Id".

For integration testing I have to drop the table and recreate it to create a defined state. Because of the dependent objects their seem to be no way to delete and recreate the table. The error message is:

> Could not drop object 'dbo.A'
>   because it is referenced by a FOREIGN
>   KEY constraint

**Question(s):**

- **How can I drop and recreate table "A"**?
- (or) is there any way turn the schema dependencies off globally?
- (or) is there any way to backup (all!) dependencies before deleting and restoring table "A" and restore all dependencies afterward?

Comment: Why don't you use a seperate DB for integration testing where the whole state is generated from scratch every time?

Comment: The database is just to big (some hundred tables with many dependent objects). Going that way, every integration test would take about a 45 seconds +x just for startup time and without any actual testing. Additionally some tables contain data. (The total database dump without any custom data is about 35MB). We will have _many_ integration tests, which we want to execute on every check in, using the integration server.

Comment: does each integration state require the same initial state of the DB, or can you pay the startup penalty once and have each test undo whatever transient changes it may have made to the state?

Comment: To pay the startup penalty once is the idea. To "rewind" the changes the idea is to recreate the table + a defined set of data. (Its huge legacy application and thats the best we come up so far. The goal are unit tests, but what we can reach currently are only integration tests.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the database in SSMS and right click. Choose tasks, generate scripts. Then go through the options and set them the way you want (Probaly to only choose foreign keys inthe table and create dependant objects and drop and recreate, dont;hve the options in front of me but you will see them. THen choose the tables you want to script the FKs for and script them to a file. Open the file and separate the drop statements into one file and the create statments into another. Now you have tweo files you can run do autmatically do what you want when ever you run run a test. I would suggest recreating the files before running the first test (in case they have changed since the last time tests were run) but not for each individual test.

Comment: Thank you, I am very grateful. That is what worked best for me!

Answer (score 5):

Explore the `sys.foreign_key_columns` system table.  Here's an example that I had laying around that will, given a table, tells you which of it's columns are keyed to another table:

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(255)
SET @tableName = 'YourTableName'

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id) AS 'FKName', OBJECT_NAME(fkc.[referenced_object_id]) AS 'FKTable', c2.[name] AS 'FKTableColumn', @tableName AS 'Table', c1.[name] AS 'TableColumn'
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns as fkc
        JOIN sys.columns AS c1 ON c1.[object_id] = fkc.[parent_object_id] AND c1.[column_id] = fkc.[parent_column_id]
        JOIN sys.columns AS c2 ON c2.[object_id] = fkc.[referenced_object_id] AND c2.[column_id] = fkc.[referenced_column_id]
    WHERE fkc.[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tableName)
    ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id)
```

With this, or some variation there-of, you could find out the foreign keys, drop them, do your stuff, and then re-create the foreign keys.

I should add that I know this works on SQL2005 and SQL2008.  I don't really know if it will work on SQL2000/MSDE.

Answer (score 4):

In Management Studio, you can right-click on the table and script the CREATE and the DROP which will include all of the foreign keys.

---

To be more specific, this will give you all constraints on which your Table depends. However, it does not give you the list of foreign keys that depend on this table. So, in addition to the scripts you would generate by right-clicking on the table in SMS, you need to find and script all the foreign keys. To get a list of them, you can run a query like so:

```
select FKConstraint.TABLE_NAME, FKConstraint.CONSTRAINT_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
    Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS As UniqueConstraint
        On UniqueConstraint.CONSTRAINT_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
    Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS As FKConstraint
        On FKConstraint.CONSTRAINT_NAME = INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_NAME        
Where UniqueConstraint.TABLE_NAME = 'TableA'
```

For each one of these, you'll need to script the create and drop. You would append the drops to the top of your drop script and the creates at the end of your create script.

Comment: This does not contain the referencing dependencies, which are the problem.

Comment: What do you mean? SMS will create a script that will drop all foreign keys to the table being dropped and then, at the end, drop the table. In addition, the create will create all the foreign keys.

Comment: Hmm, I dit try this.. and got a script with many: "IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.check_constraints WHERE" ... but when I execute it, I still get: "Could not drop object 'dbo.A' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint." This is really, really odd!

Comment: My apologies. I see the issue. You need to find all FKs that point to the table you wish to drop. I'll amend my response.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the table in Sql Server Management Studio, Expand the Constraints folder.

Write down any constraints that you have so you can re-create them.  Delete the constraints and drop the table.  Rebuild the table and re-create your constraints.

Comment: I thought about that as well but since many tables have many constraints and dependencies this is will be a lot of work. (And a lot of work is, what I try to avoid :-) )

Comment: Yes,  I wish Mircosoft would make it easier to perform this task.  Every time I have to do it, I complain loudly. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use transaction.
At the end of test - rollback it.

Comment: Nice idea, but I can't get hold of the SQL-Connection - so there is no way to control the transaction (?).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider maintaining a virtual server with your database in its initialize test setup.   Boot the VM, perform your testing, then throw away the changed VM.

Comment: No, there's no restoring at all.  It would take a minute or two to boot the VM when you wanted it, that's all.